# Dropdown selection lost in Chrome on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I'm having an error with dropdowns in Chrome (version 30, may not be specific to 30, just what i'm running) in an asp.net 4.0 /C# web app. If you select an item with key strokes and then click away from the dropdown, the selected item in the dropdown is lost.

If you tab away, or click the item the selection is retained. Has anyone else found this behavior? Is there a workaround? The ddl works fine in all other browsers.

Thanks
Ten

Comment: That's really weird: http://jsfiddle.net/3hWea/

Comment: That is odd.  I wonder if this is a bug or expected behavior.